# Spring boot: how to correctly configure and use multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I am trying to setup multiple datasources correctly in `Spring Boot with JPA 2.1.4.RELEASE`.
Setup is something like below:

- **DEV**: 1 server with 2 dbs: `DB1` and `DB2`. `DB1` has `ABC` table and `DB2` has `XYZ` table.
- **PROD**: 2 servers **PROD1** and **PROD2** both live-live. Each **PROD** server has same setup as **DEV** i.e. **PROD1** has `DB1` and `DB2`; and **PROD2** also has `DB1` and `DB2`.

So far I have successfully completed **DEV** setup. I have 2 configurations:

1. for `DB1`
2. for `DB2`

Then I have 2 Repos:

1. for `ABC` which writes in `DB1`
2. for `XYZ` which writes in `DB2`

Now in **PROD**, I need to write data in both servers(**PROD1** and **2**) in single transaction using spring boot.

I can see one example [here](https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-with-multiple-databases-example/) which try to provide some sort of solution, but problem is it will ask to create duplicate Dao and Service class, which I think is not a good way of solving this problem and need to understand how to properly configure those properties in application.properties and DataSourceConfig.java

**application-dev.properties**

```
datasource.db1.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;databaseName=db1;
datasource.db1.username=user
datasource.db1.password=pwd
datasource.db1.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

datasource.db2.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1234;databaseName=db2;
datasource.db2.username=user
datasource.db2.password=pwd
datasource.db2.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
datasource.prod1.db1.url=jdbc:sqlserver://prodserver1:1234;databaseName=db1;
datasource.prod1.db1.username=user
datasource.prod1.db1.password=pwd
datasource.prod1.db1.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

datasource.prod1.db2.url=jdbc:sqlserver://prodserver1:1234;databaseName=db2;
datasource.prod1.db2.username=user
datasource.prod1.db2.password=pwd
datasource.prod1.db2.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

datasource.prod2.db1.url=jdbc:sqlserver://prodserver2:1234;databaseName=db1;
datasource.prod2.db1.username=user
datasource.prod2.db1.password=pwd
datasource.prod2.db1.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

datasource.prod2.db2.url=jdbc:sqlserver://prodserver2:1234;databaseName=db2;
datasource.prod2.db2.username=user
datasource.prod2.db2.password=pwd
datasource.prod2.db2.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**Db1DataSourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "demo.repos.db1",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager")
public class Db1DataSourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.db1")
    public DataSourceProperties db1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource db1DataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = db1DataSourceProperties();
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = db1EntityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(db1DataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"demo.entities.db1"});
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Db2DataSourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "demo.repos.db2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager")
public class Db2DataSourceConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.db2")
    public DataSourceProperties db2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties = db2DataSourceProperties();
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = db2EntityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(db2DataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"demo.entities.db2"});
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you. Should avoid duplication. And this is easy
```java   
@Autowired @Qualifier("userDao2")
    private UserDao userDao2;
@Autowired @Qualifier("userDao1")
    private UserDao userDao1;
```

Comment: what should be the correct way of defining the configuration then so that DEV and PROD works both fiine, as in DEV we have only 1 server but PROD has 2? in application properties as well as `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.db1")`

Comment: Usually , you shouldn't write to 2 data source. Instead, DB should be clustered so that you only need care about 1 data source in programming scope.

Comment: If you have to write to 2 data source manually, then two sets of config is necessary. I think.